# Elasticsearch query strategy for nested array elements

Tags: arrays, json, elastic-map-reduce, elasticsearch

I am trying to find results by color. In the database, it is recorded in `rgb` format: an array of three numbers representing `red, green, and blue` values respectively.

Here is how it is stored in the db and elasticsearch record (storing 4 rgb colors in an array):

```
"color_data": 
    [
        [253, 253, 253], 
        [159, 159, 159], 
        [102, 102, 102], 
        [21, 21, 21]
    ]
```

Is there a query strategy that will allow me to find `similar` colors? i.e. exact match or within a close range of rgb values?

Here is a method I am trying, but the addressing method to access array values doesn't work:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 50,
    "range": {
        "color_data.0.0": {
            "gte": "#{b_lo}",
            "lte": "#{b_hi}"
        },
        "color_data.0.1": {
            "gte": "#{g_lo}",
            "lte": "#{g_hi}"
        }
    }
}'
```

(***r_lo, r_hi***, et. al. are set to +/- 10 from the rgb values recorded in the ***color_data*** variable)

Answer (score 1):

- First, you should move channel data to separate fields (or to `object` field at least)
- If you need simple matching algo (±deviation *without* scoring), then you can perform simple `filter>range` queries, passing your fuzziness threshold in query.
- If you need scoring (how *much* similar that docs are), than you need to perform scripted queries. Take a look at [this article](http://www.stichlberger.com/software/elasticsearch-color-search/)

Btw, I strongly recommend work in HSL space, if you need such operations, you'll get much better results. Take a look at [this example](http://dpb587.me/blog/2014/04/24/color-searching-with-elasticsearch.html)

Comment: I implemented this as a scripted search query per the example, but for some reason it is always returning the full record set...as if I queried match_all: {}. Not sure why this is happening...